# Disable logon prompt show hostname

Tags: security, hostname, virtual-console

Per default the login prompt shows `%hostname% login:`.

I don't want anybody with console access to see the hostname of the server that easily.

How to get rid of the hostname there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the option `--nohostname` to `getty`. Edit the files /etc/init/tty[1-9].conf to change the *exec* line from something like

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

to

```
exec /sbin/getty --nohostname -8 38400 tty1
```

It may also be necessary to edit /etc/issue to remove the `\n` escape code, which displays the hostname before the login prompt. Change it so it looks like:

```
Ubuntu XX.YY \l
```

Default text mode login screen:

[image]

Text mode login screen after adding `--nohostname` too /etc/init/tty*.conf and playing with /etc/issue:

[image]

More information:

- [getty manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/getty.8.html)
- [issue manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/pt/man5/issue.5.html)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I meant, and it works good! Thanks.